# jQuery - not getting element:enabled properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

In my form I have two divs (bench_stock_items and non_bench_stock_items) with same fields with same ids. Using jQuery I disable one and enable other depending upon the value selected in client_id select which is not part of divs. I have a function that shows/hides different forms based on values selected in media_id select which is part of divs. My function works only for the select in first div which is loaded as enabled and not for the second div that is loaded disabled. I have tried almost everything. I am able to find the element:enabled properly in first div but not in second div.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#non_bench_stock_fields :input").removeAttr("disabled", true);
        $("#bench_stock_fields :input").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#artifact_client_id").change(function () {
            if ($("#artifact_client_id option:selected").text() == "Bench Stock") {
                $("#bench_stock_fields").slideDown("fast");
                $("#bench_stock_fields :input").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#non_bench_stock_fields").slideUp("fast");
                $("#non_bench_stock_fields :input").attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#non_bench_stock_fields").slideDown("fast");
                $("#non_bench_stock_fields :input").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#bench_stock_fields").slideUp("fast");
                $("#bench_stock_fields :input").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
        $("#artifact_media_id:enabled").change(function () {
            var enabled_media_id = null;
            enabled_media_id = $("#artifact_media_id:enabled");
            var enabled_evidence_type_id = null;
            enabled_evidence_type_id = $("#artifact_evidence_type_id:enabled");

            if ($(enabled_media_id).find('option:selected').text() !== "Please select") {
                $("#show_selected_media_fields").slideDown("fast");
                $("#show_selected_media_fields :input").removeAttr("disabled", true);
                $.post("/artifacts/show_selected_media_fields", {
                    media_type: $(enabled_media_id).find('option:selected').text(),
                    evidence_type_id: $(enabled_evidence_type_id).find('option:selected').val()
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#show_selected_media_fields").html(data);
                });
            } else {
                $("#show_selected_media_fields").slideUp("fast");
                $("#show_selected_media_fields :input").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            $('#printHere').html(enabled_media_id);

        });

        $("#artifact_evidence_type_id:enabled").change(function () {
            var enabled_evidence_type_id = null;
            enabled_evidence_type_id = $("#artifact_evidence_type_id:enabled");
            if ($(enabled_evidence_type_id).find('option:selected').text() == "Deliverable, (DC)") {
                $("#logical_items_form").slideDown("fast");
                $("#logical_items_form :input").removeAttr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#logical_items_form").slideUp("fast");
                $("#logical_items_form :input").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });


    });
```

My ruby view html:

```
<div id="bench_stock_fields" class="hide">

                <li><%= f.label :evidence_number, :class => "required" %><%= f.text_field :evidence_number %></li>
                <li><%= f.label :evidence_type, :class => "required" %><%= f.collection_select(:evidence_type_id, EvidenceType.where("code='BS'"), :id, :name_and_code) %></li>     
                <li><%= f.label :media_id, :class => "required" %><%= f.collection_select(:media_id, Media.where("name = 'External Hard Drive' or name = 'Internal Hard Drive' or name = 'Thumb Drive'"), :id, :name) %></li>
                <li><%= f.label :received_location,:class => "required" %><%= select_tag(:current_location_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.where("location = 'Lab' and rack = 'N/A' and bin = 'Bench Stock'"), :id, :location_name)) %></li>        
</div>
<div id="non_bench_stock_fields" >
--- same fields as above... 
   blah... blah... blah...
```

============================================================================

OK I wrote a simplified version the code so that it is more understandable. Here is my complete code:

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>  
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css"> 
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
  <script type="text/javascript">                                         
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div_car :input").attr("disabled",true);
  $("#div_car").attr("disabled",true);  

    $("#decide").change(function(){
    if ($("#decide option:selected").text() == 'Car')             { 
              $("#div_car").slideDown("fast"); 
              $("#div_car").removeAttr("disabled");
              $("#div_car :input").removeAttr("disabled");
              $("#div_bus").slideUp("fast"); 
              $("#div_bus").attr("disabled",true);
              $("#div_bus :input").attr("disabled",true);
                } else { 
              $("#div_bus").slideDown("fast");
              $("#div_bus").removeAttr("disabled");
              $("#div_bus :input").removeAttr("disabled");
              $("#div_car").slideUp("fast");
              $("#div_car").attr("disabled",true);
              $("#div_car :input").attr("disabled",true);
              }     
    });

    $("#cars:enabled").change(function(){
    var enabled_select_id = $("#cars:enabled"); 
    $('#printHere').html(enabled_select_id);
    });

 });


</script> 


   <!-- we will add our HTML content here -->  

<div id="div_decide">
<select id = "decide" name="decide">
<option value="buss">Buss</option>
<option value="car">Car</option>
</select>
</div>   

<div id="div_car" class="hide">
<select id = "cars" name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat" selected="selected">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>   
<div id="div_bus">
<select id = "cars" name="cars">
<option value="volvo selected="selected">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
Enabled Select will print here <br/><br/>
    <span id="printHere"></span>   
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

My application.css is :

```
.hide{ display:none;}
```

Basically here is what I need to do:

I need to load div_car as disabled and hidden. Depending upon the value selected in select "decide", I need to toggle div_bus with div_car. Depending upon the value selected in CURRENTLY ENABLED select "cars" I need to show something... say print element. It only works for select car in div_bus but does not work when it is toggled with div_car.

Comment: "two divs ... with same fields with same ids." You can't have the same IDs in multiple elements. You probably should be using classes instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you use .removeAttr("disabled", true) on some inputs yet .removeAttr("disabled") on others?

Comment: Can you add more to the example?

Comment: I have to have two divs with same fields and ids or names because in database they are going to exact same table/columns. Rails handles fields via ids/names. Basically I need to toggle two divs depending upon select value in a separate select list. The displayed/enabled div has another select that triggers more fields. I am able to toggle divs with slideUp/Down and attr(disable) but the select list in second div does not work. Only the first div works as that was enabled when the page loads. I want to pluck the select in enabled div again when it is toggled. How to do that?

Comment: I think you should include the code for the 'non_bench_stock_fields' as well... there may be a conflict in there that can throw off the rest of your code.. Do you have a fiddle or a page we can look at in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using html options in rails to set differnet ids for the two collection_selects

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer...I have two questions.

First. what is the point of using the :enabled psuedo selector on change when if its disabled, you can't change it...doesnt really make sense...

Second, When I see a function like this, it makes me wonder why in the world you would want to complicate things...

```
    $("#artifact_evidence_type_id:enabled").change(function () {
        var enabled_evidence_type_id = null;
        enabled_evidence_type_id = $("#artifact_evidence_type_id:enabled");
        if ($(enabled_evidence_type_id).find('option:selected').text() == "Deliverable, (DC)") {
            $("#logical_items_form").slideDown("fast");
            $("#logical_items_form :input").removeAttr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#logical_items_form").slideUp("fast");
            $("#logical_items_form :input").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

Seems better for your sanity to write it like this...

```
    $("#artifact_evidence_type_id").change(function () {

        if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "Deliverable, (DC)") {

            $("#logical_items_form").slideDown("fast").find('input').attr("disabled", false);

        } else {

            $("#logical_items_form").slideUp("fast").find('input').attr("disabled", true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Good points: 1. When I don't use  :enabled selector it always defaults to the first div even if it is disabled. 2. var enabled_evidence_type_id = null; is an attempt for it to unset the selected element variable and reset it. I was doing what you suggested before and that did not work either.

Comment: since there are two selects with same id it always takes the first select which in my case is disabled and never fires.

Comment: I have to do that. However how can we make it loop through all selects of id="cars" and get only the one that is :enabled?

Comment: find the id for the :enabled select and fire my logic when it changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had this one working in my HTML meanwhile. But it was not working in my rails project. So I figured out a way to have different Ids for selects in cars and buses. It works now. Thanks for all your help. Best regards,

Comment: @user1570144 Before you go, check out the revised fiddle, may help you cut down your code a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/m7aXa/  Also, will you click the check mark next to my answer to accept it?